# sprin2.5 + quartz scheduler...org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to use cron trigger for my app which has spring2.5

I followed http://www.a2ztechguide.com/2011/11/spring-quartz-scheduler-integration.html this link in creating a simple pgm.. But while trying to dpeloy it to my server(weblogic 10g)...Im getting the below exception....

```
<Aug 8, 2013 6:17:31 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener
     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed:
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
  with name 'printCurrentTimeJobDetail' defined in URL [file:/C:/bea/user_projects
 /workspaces/One_CMS_Offline/Services/build/onecms-service.xml]: Initialization of 
bean failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/JobDetail     
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'printCurrentTimeJobDetail' defined in URL [file:/C:/bea/user_projects/workspaces/One_CMS_Offline/Services/build/onecms-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/JobDetail
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/JobDetail
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1272)
at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1270)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Can someone pls tell mw where Im going wrong?  I included these 2 jars: **spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar** and **com.springsource.org.quartz-1.6.2.jar**

> Can someone pls suggest some solution here..

Answer (score 0):

you have to include quartz related jar in your classpath, which version of quartz are you using?

according to the link you posted, you should add quartz dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are not using maven, include quartz.jar in your classpath as you do with spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar

--edit--

seems odd, you don't happen to have multiple copies of the quartz in WEB-INF/lib? what is the com.springsource.org.quartz-1.6.2.jar for? try exclude it from WEB-INF/lib

Comment: i dont have any pom.xml in my proj

Comment: and then download quartz-1.6.3.jar and include it in classpath

Comment: i already included the quartz1.6.3 jar in the same path where i included other jars

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you have included the quartz related jars also .

Add the latest quartz jar to your server/lib from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.0) .

Thanks

Comment: do i need to include quartz 2.o instead of 1.6?

Comment: would suggest to go with the latest stable version.

Comment: careful with quartz version and spring...quartz 2.x is not supported by spring until 3.1 RC2: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8727. If you're not using that version, stay with quartz 1.x (latest in that line is 1.8.6 i believe)